# How do I find my local SQLite database file in Apache Airflow?

Tags: sqlite, airflow

I'm new to Apache Airflow and tried to use a SQLite database backend.

When I run the SQL queries in my DAG, I get a success code 0 and the logs show that the queries are being executed successfully. Problem is when I check the default database created at installation, sqlite:////home/ademusire/airflow/airflow.db, the table I created from my DAG is not there. As I didn't create any other database, I don't know where else it could be.

Please how do I locate the db file where my queries are being executed?

The code from my DAG.py is written below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

from airflow import DAG 

from airflow.providers.sqlite.operators.sqlite import SqliteOperator

default_args = {
    "owner": "ademusire",
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=2)
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="dag_with_sqlite_operator_v06",
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 12, 23),
    schedule_interval="@daily"
) as dag:

    task1 = SqliteOperator(
        task_id="create_table_sqlite",
        sql=r"""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tripdata_monthly_statistics(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            month TEXT,
            sat_mean_trip_count NUMERIC,
            sat_mean_fare_per_trip NUMERIC,
            sat_mean_duration_per_trip NUMERIC,
            sun_mean_trip_count NUMERIC,
            sun_mean_fare_per_trip NUMERIC,
            sun_mean_duration_per_trip NUMERIC
            );
        """,
    )
    
    task2 = SqliteOperator(
        task_id="insert_into_table",
        sql=r"""
            INSERT INTO tripdata_monthly_statistics(id, month, 
            sat_mean_trip_count, sat_mean_fare_per_trip, sat_mean_duration_per_trip,
            sun_mean_trip_count, sun_mean_fare_per_trip, sun_mean_duration_per_trip)
            VALUES(1, '2023-11', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
        """,
    ) 

    task3 = SqliteOperator(
        task_id="select_from_table",
        sql=r"""SELECT * FROM tripdata_monthly_statistics;""",
    )

    task4 = SqliteOperator(
        task_id="show_tables",
        sql=r"""
            SELECT 
                name
            FROM 
                sqlite_schema
            WHERE 
                type ='table' AND 
                name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%';
        """,
    )

    task1 >> task2 >> task3 >> task4
```

When I ran `airflow config get-value database sql_alchemy_conn`, it outputed sqlite:////home/ademusire/airflow/airflow.db as the database I'm connected to but the new table I created was not there. I don't know how to create a new SQLIte database where the queries from the task I run in my DAG will be executed and I can't find the current one where my new table is stored. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow metadata database and the database SqliteOperator is connecting to are two different dbs. You probably don't want to run any operations on Airflow's database, maybe unless scheduling some maintenance DAGs that operate on Airflow internals.

[The operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sqlite/stable/operators.html) takes an argument named `sqlite_conn_id` which defines the database. If you didn't provide it explicitly, then it took a default value of `sqlite_default`. Its details can be found in UI (Admin -> Connections) or via API/CLI:

```
$ airflow connections get sqlite_default
id | conn_id        | conn_type | host                   
===+================+===========+========================
49 | sqlite_default | sqlite    | /tmp/sqlite_default.db
```

Now if you open this database you will probably find your table.

The best approach would be not to rely on a default connection, but explicitly define your own (->[docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html)) and use that in the operator.

Comment: Since I posted the question, I continued to search for solutions online and found a tutorial that showed how to create a new SQLite db using the terminal and then create a new connection to that database using the UI (Admin -> Connections). I saw this tutorial before I saw your answer. Just like you wrote, the best approach is to explicitly define a new connection and pass the value of the connection id set in the UI to the `sqlite_conn_id` argument of the SqliteOperator. Thank you.